# Redirect to shop page if WooCommerce cart is emptied in checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, woocommerce, checkout

Using the code below, the customer is able to remove an item from the cart when on checkout, but if removing all items - the customer should be re-directed to the shop page.

I have tried the code below which does not work correctly, the customer is still left on the "`The checkout is not available when your cart is empty`", which is followed by a button to take the customer to the shop.

The idea is not just to re-direct, but also to display a message using `wc_add_notice`.

**The first part of the code is this:**

```
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'product_thumbnail_and_remove_on_checkout', 20, 3 );
    function product_thumbnail_and_remove_on_checkout( $product_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    if ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) {
        $cart = WC()->cart->get_cart();
        foreach ($cart as $cart_key => $cart_value){
            if ($cart_key == $cart_item_key){
                $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
                $_product = $cart_item['data'] ;
                $remove_product = sprintf(
                    '<a class="remove" style="float:left;margin-right:5px;" href="%s" title="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" data-cart_item_key="%s">&times;</a>',
                    esc_url(wc_get_cart_remove_url( $cart_key)),
                    __( 'Remove From Order', 'woocommerce' ),
                    esc_attr($product_id),
                    esc_attr($_product->get_sku()),
                    esc_attr($cart_item_key)
                );
            }
        }
        $product = $cart_item['data'];
        $thumbnail = $product->get_image(array(50, 50));
        $image_html = '<div class="product-item-thumbnail">' . $thumbnail . '</div>';
        $product_name_link = '<a class="pnoc" href="' . $product->get_permalink() . '">' . $product_name . '</a>';
        $product_name = $remove_product . $image_html . $product_name_link;
    }
    return $product_name;
}
```

**The code I am trying to make work:**

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'cart_js_on_checkout', 10 );
function cart_js_on_checkout() {

    if ( is_checkout() ) {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'wc-cart' );
    }
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_empty_checkout_to_shop' );
function redirect_empty_checkout_to_shop() {

    if ( is_checkout() && WC()->cart->is_empty() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-pay' ) && ! is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' ) ) {

    wp_safe_redirect( wc_get_page_permalink( 'shop') );
    
    wc_clear_notices();
    wc_add_notice( __( 'The checkout is not available when your cart is empty. Happy shopping!', 'woocommerce' ), 'info' );
    
    }
}
```

Comment: There, that's a little easier to read...

Comment: Yes, true. Thank you. I should have formatted the first part better. Is there a `template_redirect` solution to this?

Comment: If I understand right you want to redirect the user after the last item is removed from the shopping cart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were near. Replace your last function with the following, that will redirect to shop page when cart is emptied in checkout (or in cart), displaying a notice in shop page:

```php
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_empty_checkout_to_shop' );
function redirect_empty_checkout_to_shop() {
    // Targetting empty cart on cart and checkout pages
    if ( ( ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) || is_cart() ) && WC()->cart->is_empty() ) {
        // Clear and add notices before the redirection function
        wc_clear_notices();
        // Argument "info" doesn't work with wc_add_notice() function
        wc_add_notice( __( 'The checkout is not available when your cart is empty. Happy shopping!', 'woocommerce' ), 'notice' ); 
        wp_safe_redirect( wc_get_page_permalink( 'shop') );
        exit(); // Always use exit after a wp redirect
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

Answer (score 0):

**If I understand right:**
You want to redirect the user right after the last item is removed from the shopping cart?

Now on my copy of Wordpress and Woo, when I remove items from the cart the page isn't reloaded.  Only part of the page is updated with AJAX ( I think you can change this in Woo).

So the 'template hook'  probably isn't being called between the remove cart and what you see on the page.  You may still want the 'template hook' part, in case the user navigates to the cart when it's empty. That will redirect them out of there.

But if it's happing in AJAX on the cart page you can try this in addition to what you have above:

```
function redirect_cart_when_empty() {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript"> 
;( function( $, window, document, undefined ) {
   "use strict";
   $( document ).ready( function() {
         $(document.body).on("wc_cart_emptied", function(){
              window.location.replace("'.wc_get_page_permalink( 'shop').'");
          });
    } );
 } ) ( jQuery, window, document );
</script>';
}
add_action('woocommerce_before_cart_table', 'redirect_cart_when_empty');
```

I'll try to explain what we want, so if it doesn't work you maybe can figure it out.  Basically we can use a javascript (jQuery ) trigger from Woo on the front end ( client side ) to initiate some simple javascript that will do the redirect/reload.

There isn't much documentation on these hooks but the one I chose hopefully gets fired by Woo when the cart is emptied.  Once we have some Javascript going and we can tell the cart is empty we can simply redirect the page using to the Shop permalink.

I just put my "Standard" jQuery wrapper stuff around it...  I'm not an expert at jQuery, I just dabble a little.

I'm not sure exactly when this hook is used, but there are a couple other that could be used such as `removed_from_cart`, `cart_totals_refreshed` etc. Which wouldn't be as clean but you could then check the total in the cart and do the redirect etc...  Maybe there is an "empty cart button" that triggers it?  I don't know.

One last note is I think `window.location.replace()` is preferable, because that will remove using the back button to go back to the empty cart and get redirected back to the shop.  That just saves the user a little hassle had we just used `window.location.href` instead.

You could also simply reload the page and allow the "template hook" to do the redirect with `window.location.reload();` then you don't need to mix PHP in with the javascript.